# Migrating ASP.NET Webforms to MVC : mixing websites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-state

We currently have an WebForm Website written en Net2, with more than 10 000 000 visits per day. We are in charge of moving it to MVC in Net 4. We can not migrate it directly because of business impacts and the huge number of features.

Our idea is to develop one or more new website in MVC .Net 4 (with a new architecture), that correspond to a business domain (marketing, finance, account..). The old site become some kind of portail (links to different web sites).

During migration, Session User data will be shared with a distributed cache like AppFabric.

Can you confirm to me it is a good approach ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Maybe DB + Transactions are more efficient way to do this, because AppFabric stores it's data in memory and there's a small percent you can loss you information.